# View counter not caching

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created view counter as generic handler in ASP.NET here is code, method `AddPostView` performes simple SQL command like "View = View +1"

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {         
            if (UrlManipulation.IsRoutedValueInt(context.Request["ID"]))
            {
                int PostID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["ID"]);

                PostManipulation.AddPostView(PostID);
            }

            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));

            context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Here is how I call it in the page markup:

```
 <img id="counter" runat="server" src="" />
```

And I set src dinamicly on page load:

```
  counter.Src = "/handlers/CountView.ashx?ID=" + post.ID.ToString();
```

But I cannot get it to cache, ie. not count additional views after user first visited this site, i tried wrapping it in as css stylesheet but same thing nothing happens, when i run firebug on it, it doesn't even show it under downloaded images or under css but it still hits it and i get another view counted.How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you set it on img, but did not return any image, so the browser did not cache it. Try this code:

```
// 1x1 transparent GIF
private readonly byte[] GifData = {
    0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff,
    0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
    0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b
};

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
     if (UrlManipulation.IsRoutedValueInt(context.Request["ID"]))
     {
        int PostID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["ID"]);
        PostManipulation.AddPostView(PostID);
     }

    // set the cache    
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10));
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

    // send the image
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
    context.Response.Buffer = false;
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(GifData, 0, GifData.Length);
}
```

Comment: Actually now I'm getting the image but response is "200 OK" instead of "304 Not Modifed"

Comment: @user1010609 the not modified is come from the server if you use a special check, the 200 OK is if its get it from local cache.

Comment: Well it still counting when ever I load page, I will try to mess around with cache options.

Comment: @user1010609 You can not 100% sure about this type of cache. If you hit reload the browser may chose to reload the image even if its on cache. To solve this type you can use session, or cookies, or connect the cookie with the page (the user with the page)... some times thinks need more code and database to solve.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I will try with session.